# Angels came and ministered to Him. Matthew 4:11 NKJV

Tags: matthew, jesus, angels

What does it mean when the Bible said that Angels came and ministered to Jesus after He was tempted by the devil?

Comment: Are you suggesting that a simple reading of the text is not appropriate here?

Comment: Give us a hint where you are trying to take this or the context of the broader discussion this question was derived from. Angels are modern day couriers, the fact that they served Him might speak to the previous temption that refers to angels being sent to protect.

Comment: According to this verse, Angels did come to minister to Him. In our modern sense, Angels are more or less spirits. So I just want to find out were these Angels physically present, where they spirit and Jesus was in the Spirit? Was the devil physically present or did this temptation happen in the spirit realm? The bible doesn't quite state if this was a physical event or spirit @Autodidact

Comment: According to this verse, Angels did come to minister to Him. In our modern sense, Angels are more or less spirits. So I just want to find out were these Angels physically present, where they spirit and Jesus was in the Spirit? Was the devil physically present or did this temptation happen in the spirit realm? The bible doesn't quite state if this was a physical event or spirit @Autodidact

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jesus was in the desert regions. Jesus had eaten nothing for forty days and forty nights. After such a time of deprivation, he would not - humanly - have had the strength to get back to civilisation to find food. Close to death from starvation, and now no longer capable - independently - of obtaining food, Jesus was in dire need of help.

*Malak* in Hebrew is not specific and can mean either 'messenger' or 'angel'. It is translated both ways, mostly 'messenger' and Malachi bears the word as his name.

But I think that the Greek *aggelos* is more specific than the Hebrew. And the abundant use of the word in the book of the Revelation indicates just how much angelic activity there is on earth - and, particularly, in association with the Gospel of God and with the people of God.

Also, the wording of the text in question, Matthew 4:11 :

> Then the devil leaveth him, and, behold, angels came and ministered unto him [KJV]

indicates a juxtaposition of Diabolos and the 'messengers/angels' who ministered to him and I would see that there is almost a certainty that these were angelic beings sent on this specific occasion to protect and to succour Jesus in his extreme condition.

Comment: So pretty much the same way the devil was able to appear and tempt Jesus, howbeit physically or spiritually, it's the same way angels appeared and fed him!

Answer (score 3):

Here the simple meaning is correct. After Jesus was tempted by Satan Angels came to him to encourage him in a sense.

Jesus spends 40 days and 40 nights in the wilderness. During that time, he eats nothing. Then, when Jesus is very hungry, Satan the Devil approaches to tempt him, saying: “If you are a son of God, tell these stones to become loaves of bread.” This must have been hard for him and he would need encouragement.

Comment: +1 for the insight about hunger. Do you think the angels brought him food? cf. [1 Kings 19:5](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/1ki/19/5/t_conc_310005)

Answer (score 0):

A spirit led life outside the realm of the world, will most definitely reveal things that we never see in the "actual real world". A world full of corruption, sometimes giving us a glimpse, even able to look inside the hearts and minds of people! Being led by the spirit will reveal things that someday will shock the world. The gift of Prophecy is one of those attributes we receive according to our faith. Surly Christ may have had a sense  of these things but without the  experience. Must we be at our weakest in the flesh to know the power of God? This is why we need to abide in Him, for we are not able to resist the wiles of Satan. This is what we see as Christ abides in His Fathers will, resisting the evil one.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).